# Add project dependency in build.sbt

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I am new to play framework. I have two play java projects. I want the proj-A to use the java classes in proj-B. I am searching for a way to do it in a build.sbt file. following are my build.sbt files

```
name := "proj-A"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    cache
)     
play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

---

```
name := "proj-B"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    cache
)    
play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Note: proj-A and proj-B are in the same directory.

```
my-folder
|_proj-A
|_proj-B
```

I am using IntelliJ. Any help on how to add the project dependency is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for a multi-project build: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html

Comment: thanks. I tried the tutorial but it is very unclear for me. A working example would be perfect for me.